# Авторизация на сайте при помощи сертификата p12 и пароля

Tags: java, авторизация, pkcs#12

У меня есть сертификат-файл AUTH_RSA256_8827cdaa76b01019066fbe4d914d67a0e31677bc.p12 и пароль выданный администратором обслуживающего сервера.
Как средствами java авторизоваться для дальнейшего парсинга.
Цель программки подключиться, предоставить сертификат, далее на странице авторизации в личную учетную запись имеется 2 RadioButton `a)` и  `b)` и поле для ввода пароля (который совпадает с паролем от ключа), выбрать `b)` и ввести пароль, (пройти внутреннюю авторизацию),  далее уже при помощи jsoup увидеть новые строки таблицы и вывести мне сообщение о новых строках. Постоянно смотреть в браузер и кликать "обновить" не трудно, но очень неудобно...

При помощи кода (и консультаций) мне удалось только получить доступ (ошибочно) и спарсить страницу, в которой необходимо предоставить сертификат, в которой имеется кнопка "Выберите ключ"

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" name="selectP12File" id="selectP12File" value="Выберите ключ"
       onclick="selectP12File()" type="button">
```

Вот сам код:

```
  KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    clientStore.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\AUTH_RSA256_8827cdaa76b01019066fbe4d914d67a0e31677bc.p12"),
            "mypassword".toCharArray());

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(clientStore, "mypassword".toCharArray());
    KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();

    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre-9.0.4\\lib\\security\\cacerts"),
            "changeit".toCharArray());

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(trustStore);
    TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();

    SSLContext sslContext = null;
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(kms, tms, new SecureRandom());



    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    URL url = new URL("https://server/ru/user/login");

    HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    if (urlConn != null) {

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("****** Content of the URL ********");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
        String input;

        while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(input);
        }
        br.close();

    } else {
        System.out.println("not connect");
    }

    urlConn.disconnect();
```

Предварительно в cacerts и команд keytool был добавлен сертификат сервера.

Прошу поделиться опытом. 
Буду рад конструктивной критике и Вашему мнению что делаю не так.
Благодарю за внимание!

Comment: Попробуйте тут посмотреть: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7016969/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я находил это решение, и пытался его реализовать, и выходит ошибка в этом участке кода

Comment: Какая ошибка и в каком участке кода?

Comment: KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("cacerts"), "mypasswod".toCharArray()); Ошибка что не находит файл "cacerts", совсем непонятно зачем эти строки и какую роль играют. по идее у меня у же есть файл р12. Который через браузер без проблем работает... Если вместо "cacerts" вставить "мой-путь.р12" то другая ошибка продолжение...

Comment: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: @ЮрийСПб HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        URL url = new URL("_https_://server/ru/user/login");

        HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        if (urlConn != null) {

            System.out.println("****** Content of the URL ********");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
            String input;

            while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(input);
            }

Comment: }
            br.close();

        } else {
            System.out.println("not connect");
        }

        urlConn.disconnect();

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ошибка _Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:_ в строке BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

Comment: Укажите всё это в вопросе, не в комментарии - так может кто-то и сможет что-то сказать. В комментариях код почти не читаем(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб т.е. нажать на "Ответить на собственный вопрос" ? и там все подробно описать ?

Comment: Нет, отредактируйте свой вопрос, через правку оного. Это кнопка внизу вопроса под метками: [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/875824/edit)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб правильно ли я все отредактировал ?

Comment: В целом да, но логи ошибки тоже надо добавить

Answer (score 1):

Указанный вами [ответ с англоязычной версии](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7016969/5506820) является правильным. Однако тут надо вставить немного разъяснений. Существует ***клиентская*** и ***серверная*** подписи. Смею предположить, что администратор выдал вам сертификат и ключ(!) в хранилище формата `.p12` для ***клиентской*** подписи. Вот пример создание подписи клиентского запроса:

```
KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
clientStore.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\AUTH_RSA256_8827cdaa76b01019066fbe4d914d67a0e31677bc.p12"),
        "mypasswod".toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(clientStore, "mypassword".toCharArray());
KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

//обратите внимание на второй параметр, т.е. мы доверяем списку  сертификатов по умолчанию
sslContext.init(kms, null, new SecureRandom());

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

URL url = new URL("https://server/ru/user/login");

HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

if (urlConn != null) {

    System.out.println("****** Content of the URL ********");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
    String input;

    while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(input);
    }
    br.close();

} else {
    System.out.println("not connect");
}

urlConn.disconnect();
```

Но. Учитывая ваш необычный URL с https `https://server/ru/user/login` (домен не публичный, потому скорее всего он подписан самоподписанным сертификатом) скорее всего вам придётся сделать некие манипуляции со списком доверенных сертификатов (списком сертификатов ***серверных*** подписей, которым мы доверяем). Это: либо добавить сертификат этого домена в *хранилище доверенных сертификатов по умолчанию*, либо создать своё *хранилище доверенных сертификатов* с нужным сертификатом внутри и указать его при создании соединения.

В ссылке, которую вы указали, использовался именно второй вариант

```
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("cacerts"), "changeit".toCharArray());

TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(trustStore);
    TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();
```

Однако не было явно указано, что это хранилище надо ещё создать, потому у вас падала ошибка, что не находит файл "cacerts". Но я покажу первый вариант. Для начала нужно стащить сертификат с вашего сайта `https://server/ru/user/login`. Для этого откройте  его в браузере, нажмите слева от домена на замок -> просмотреть сертификат -> вкладка "Подробности" ->экспортировать. Обратить внимание на то, что поле `CN` в сертификате должно соответствовать домену. Вот картинка с примером:

[image: Пример]

Хранилище сертификатов по умолчанию лежит по адресу `%JRE_HOME%/lib/security/cacerts`, где `%JRE_HOME%` - путь к JRE. Добавить к нему ещё один сертификат можно при помощи утилиты **keytool.exe**, встроенной в **JRE** (`%JRE_HOME%/bin/keytool.exe`) примерно такой командой:

```
%JRE_HOME%/bin/keytool.exe -importcert -file 'path/myTrustCert.cer' -alias 'myTrustCert' -keystore `%JRE_HOME%/lib/security/cacerts` -storepass 'changeit'
```

, где `-file 'path/myTrustCert.cer'` - сертификат (желательно указывать полный путь), который мы взяли ранее с сайта, `-storepass 'changeit'` - пароль по умолчанию для хранилища по умолчанию, `-alias 'myTrustCert'` - псевдоним для нового сертификата (особой роли не играет, главное чтобы не пересекался с другими сертификатами в этом хранилище).

После Ваша программа должна заработать, если конечно мое предположение является правильным.

Comment: Благодарю за очень подробные разъяснения, Темка тоже, вы абсолютно правы, все прошло на "ура", но прошу великодушно простить, я увидел контент сайта в котором увидел знакомые строки,     <input class="btn btn-primary" name="selectP12File" id="selectP12File" value="Выберите ключ"
           onclick="selectP12File()" type="button"> Вот теперь, если я правильно понимаю, я должен отправить ключ + пароль. Как сайту еще раз его отправить ?

Comment: Т.е. я спарсил страницу в которую я вхожу, нажимаю "Выберите ключ", ввожу пароль, и получаю доступ к нужной таблице

Comment: @p_redator Для начала ответьте на главный вопрос. Требует ли  сервер  **подписания запроса на уровне ssl** (клиентской подписи)? Или он требует отправки ключа, что выдал вам администратор , при помощи HTML-формы, (что вообще противоречит здравой логике)? Из комментариев выше также мало понятно, контент какого сайта вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: Попробую все разложить по полочкам. Общий сценарий входа такой. 1) проходим по адресу `https://server/ru/user/login` и браузер (chrome) выводит окно c выбором сертификата который был загружен ранее, (тот самый что указан в коде C:\\AUTH_RSA256_) 2) выдаёт окно с выбором окно одного из двух RadioButton ( `a)` или `b)` ) и ввожу пароль точно такой же как от сертификата (ощущение что здесь двойная авторизация, сперва по ключу, дальше по паролю), пройдя её я попадаю на страничку `https://server/ru/searchanno` где провожу поиск нужной мне информации,  которую я и хотел бы получить

Comment: Далее я думал сгенерить такую строку что выдал мне браузер `https://server/ru/searchanno?binname=&numberAnno=&titleAnno=&region_supply=11&plan_amoun_start=&plan_amoun_end=&methodz=0&statuses=0&date_start=&date_end=&subj_type=0` результатом будет таблица из 10 столбцов  и спарсить её

Comment: Теперь такой момент без Вашей поправки в коде у меня небыло результата, если спарсить `https://mail.ru` закоментировав  весь код связанный с работой сертификата то проблем нет, Возможно я ошибаюсь но может действовать как по выше описанному сценарию 1) сперва предоставить Сертификат что лежит в `cacerts` 2) отправить сертификат `C:\\AUTH_RSA256_` 3) выбрать  `RadioButton b)` и ввести пароль. Далее уже пройдя все круги авторизации переходить на `https://server/ru/searchanno?` и вот там уже парсить

Comment: @p_redator. Судя по вашему описания, у вас какой-то костыльно-прикладной метод авторизации на вашем сайте. Т.к. обычно, сертификат тоже не отсылается на сервер (иначе получается, что сервер доверяет сертификату пользователя,  который загрузил сам пользователь), а добавляется туда администратором. Потому помочь я более не могу. Или уточните описание, желательно со скриншотами.

Comment: Темка тоже что именно уточнить ? и скрин чего Вам бы понадобился ? может можем воспользоваться скайпом или майл-агентом ?

Comment: Темка тоже, возможно я не правильно выразился не отправить сертификат а предоставить

Comment: @p_redator На прямой контакт пойти не могу, если вы можете внести уточнения, то следует править вопрос.

Comment: Темка тоже, задать новый вопрос со всеми уточнениями или редактировать текущий? P.S. C профессиональным праздником, мастера исходного кода!

Comment: @p_redator, редактируйте текущий

Comment: @ Темка тоже, подредактировал сам вопрос, я конечно новичок в этих делах, но мелькнула идея, что может легче (правильнее) использовать cookies. Т.е. авторизоваться обычным способом, подхватить cookies браузера и дальше уже отправлять запросы как авторизованный пользователь, но хотелось бы разобраться в вышеописанном вопросе

Comment: @p_redator https://habr.com/company/dataart/blog/262817/ В твоём случае интерес представляют разделы "Forms authentication"  и "Аутентификация по сертификатам"